# Python Bit Operations on a list of Int's

Tags: python, list, int, immutability, mutable

What I want to do that does not work:
List of ints...

```
BebossArray=[0 for i in xrange(1024)]
```

My bit functions (There are all the usual set,clear,toggle, test but here is set)

```
def setBit(dint, offset):
mask = 1 << offset
dint=(dint|mask)
return
```

so I would like to set a bit in one of the ints in the list...

```
setBit(DebossArray[index],3)
```

This, of course, does not work. The assignment in setBit just creates a new object and DebossArray[index] stays put as expected. So I get that INT's are immuttable so I can't do a change in place.

What I did... (I don't like it but it works for my purposes)

```
DebossArray=[ctypes.c_int32() for x in xrange(1024)]
```

and

```
def setBit(dint, offset):
mask = 1 << offset
dint.value=(dint.value|mask)
return
```

so now

```
setBit(DebossArray[index],3]
```

works as expect because ctype.c_int32() IS mutable so I can modify it in place.

I am using 2.7 but rolling up to 3 will probably happen later in the project.I am also trying to stay away from

```
DebossArray[index]=setBit(DebossArray[index],3)
```

type of construct.

More detail:
In some places I have DebossArray[x] and in other places I have ButtonArray[x][y]

And now to the point;
What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over complicating this, just return the result and rebind the original name:

```
def setBit(dint, offset):
    mask = 1 << offset
    return dint | mask

r = 0
r = setBit(r, 5)
# 32
```

You don't really even need a function, you could just do:

```
i = 0
i |= (1 << 5)
# 32
```

Comment: I was specifically trying to stay away from r=setBit(r,5) construct.

Comment: @Burtski Well, this and your `DebossArray[index]=setBit(DebossArray[index],3)` is pretty much as good as it gets without making it convoluted...

Comment: Well as much as I wanted to stay away from the r=setBit(r,x) construct, that appears to be the only clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class like this:

```
class BebossArray(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._l = [0 for i in xrange(1024)]

    def setBit(self, index, offset):
        self._l[index] = (self._l[index]|1 << offset)
```

Or just make setBit accept a list, index, and offset and replace the value at the index with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
DebossArray = [0 for i in xrange(4)]

def setBit(dint, index, offset):
    dint[index] |= 1 << offset

print DebossArray  # [0, 0, 0, 0]
setBit(DebossArray, 2, 3)
print DebossArray  # [0, 0, 8, 0]
```